# How to set title while sharing in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, yii2

hi i am using the following code to create a fb share button

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>">Facebook</a>
```

so using this i can share the `url`. i also want to set the title, i.e, in `facebook` share option there is a field "say something about this". i want to fill that field with a default value. is there any way?
i tried like this but it didn't work

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]&t=movie"; ?>">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: The sharer does not take any other parameters besides the URL to share any more, but will instead take all of that additional data from the Open Graph meta tags of that URL. If you want to specify those values dynamically, you need to use the Feed dialog instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set the title, but read on for more information. Add the meta tag below to the page you are sharing.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title">
```

The "say something about this" default you have no control over sorry.

**More information:**

You want to setup a Facebook AppID for your website so you can customise Facebook features in future.

But below I have shown some basic meta tags you need to use to customise what is shown on Facebook when your page is shared. These go on each page you are wanting to share. More information is here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yoururl.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your Description.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoururl.com/image.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site Name">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="Your App ID (numerical)">
```

Note: You will have to use [Facebook Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to remove previously stored caching on this page. Also any previously shared content will most likely not be effected.